# GAMLSS: What exactly is the predicted or fitted sigma? why can't I use it to calculate z-score?

Tags: standard-deviation, z-score, gamlss, predict.gamlss

The question I have is previously posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74985034/r-gamlss-predicting-standard-deviation-and-calculating-z-scores) in detail by someone else but the main question is not answered.
what exactly is the fitted sigma? Is it always standard deviation?
If yes, why can't it be used to calculate Z-scores as in this formula:
z = (y - mu)/sigma

Answer (score 1):

In GAMLSS sigma is generally a scale parameter,
but not usually the standard deviation.

If you want the z-score for any distribution,
then it is given by:

first find the probability p of being below the observed y value (i.e. the cdf at y), given the fitted parameters,

e.g. for a BCT(mu, sigma,nu,tau) distribution

p = pBCT(y,mu,sigma,nu,tau)

Then find the inverse cdf of a standard normal at this p

z = qNO(p)

Then z is the z-score.

The above 2 lines of R code give the z-score for ANY continuous distribution.
The z-score is interpreted for non-normal distributions in the same way as for normal distributions,
e.g a z-score above 1.96 shows that the observed y is in the 2.5% upper tail of the its fitted distribution (given its values of the explanatory variables).

Do NOT use qBCT.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is it okay to use qNO on non-normal distributions? why not use qBCT here for example? Also is it valid to use zscore for non-normal distributions? is the interpretation the same?